# how to count the occurrences of a word in a line in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My goal is to print the count of a word occurrences in a list of files but the problem is that my code considers the occurrence as 1 even if the word exists in a line more than once
ex : like like like like
the output is 1 not 4.

```
import os
import math
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

nltk.download('stopwords')
stopwords= set(stopwords.words('english'))
folderpath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Documents"
word = input("Choose a word : ")

for(path, dirs, files) in os.walk(folderpath, topdown=True):

    for file in files:

        counter = 0
        idf = 0
        filepath = os.path.join(path, file)
        with open(filepath, 'r') as f:

            info = f.readlines()
            for line in f:

                if word in str(info).casefold() and word not in stopwords:

                    for line in info:

                        if word in line:


                            counter=counter+1 
                            idf = 1 + math.log10(counter)    



        weight = idf * counter

        print("The tf in" + " " + os.path.splitext(file)[0] + " "+ "is :" + " " +  " " +  str(counter))
        print ("The idf is" + ":" + " "+ str(idf))
        print("The weight is"+":" + " " + str(weight))
        print(" ")
```

the results are :
the document's name and the term-frequency
then the inverse-document-frequency
them the weight
but I expected the same result except :
the term-frequency "which is the counter of the occurrences" has to be the number of word's occurrences in the file but actually it is the number of the word's occurrences in each lines as the following : add 1 to the counter if the word in the line regardless of the number of the occurrences

Comment: I may be missing something, but wouldnt this suffice as the core algorithm:

import re
target_word = 'am'
line = " I am having a very nice day am."
all_words = re.findall(r'\w+', line)
number_of_target_words = len([word for word in all_words if word == target_word])
# then sum all of the 'number_of_target_words' for all files

Comment: assume that we have a text document that has 1 line 
"like like is like like is like "
and if we run this code on this document and we want to look for the word "like" then the output would be 1 coz the word "like" exists in the line.
I want the code to print the number of occurrences not just 1 if the word exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are having issues because of:

```
            if word in str(info).casefold() and word not in stopwords:

                for line in info:

                    if word in line:


                        counter=counter+1 
                        idf = 1 + math.log10(counter)
```

This is only adding 1 to your "counter" for each line that has a match.

I think you would be much better off using re.findall on each line and then counting the result of re.findall into your "counter"

Please see my code below, although it is not a full solution I think you can see how it could be inserted into your code.

```
import re

Mylist = ("like like like like like like", "right ike left like herp derp") # This is in place of your files.

word = "like" # word to look for
counter = 0

for i in Mylist: # in your code this would be "for line in f:"
    search = re.findall(word, i) # use re.findall to search for all instances of your word in given line.
    for i in search: # then for every word returned by re.findall in that line count them into your counter.
        counter = counter + 1

print(counter)
```

This code returns,

```
7
```

There is further optimisation, as you are using re.findall you do not need to read your file line by line, you can look at the whole file at once like this.

```
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        info = f.read()
        search = re.findall(word, info)
        for i in search:
            counter = counter + 1
```

This should return the same and have one less layer in your loop.

Comment: first of all thank u, but I really don`t know where to add your code coz I tried to add it and in did not work :(

Comment: It worked, thanks alot Pedro, I`ll mark it as an answer

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I was just working on a further answer.

Comment: please if u can declare what does import re mean and the function findall

Comment: import re, is to import the regex module, just the same as you have for import os, or import math.

Comment: re.findall(pattern, string) is a regex function to find all instances of a pattern in given string, in your case to find all instances of your word in the file text. it will return that as a list and in this case you are then counting the items in that list to your "counter" but you could do whatever you wanted with it.